# get the '/foo' out of 'http://someplace.com/index.php/foo'

Tags: php

As far as I know php has an function to get the '/foo/bar/' out of a URL like: 'http://someplace.com/index.php/foo/bar/'

Can't remember what the function is called.

**[edit]**

I remember using something like this in ExpressionEngine ([see this](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/usage/uri.html)). And later coming over an article explaining such a function build in PHP. However I can't recall what it was.

**[edit #2]**

I know that there are functions to get out the URL and several to manipulate it. However I clearly remember that there were one function doing just this specific thing. Look at the [ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/usage/uri.html) example I linked to too get a better understanding of what I mean.

**[edit #3]**

It wasn't ExpressionEngine I had used. [It was CodeIngniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html). But it's basically the same thing.

**[edit #4]**

Maybe I am wrong. I just remembering walking over just such a function in an article once...
Case closed (unless someone stumble upon just such a function).

Comment: use Apache/Lighthttp or your favorite webserver to use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to pass the s.c. "query" into your main.php to route the "query".

Comment: If `http://example.com/index.php/foo/bar/` is not the current URL, then how is that `http://example.com/index.php` to be identified?

Comment: Out damned foo! as Shakespeare didn't say

Comment: There are functions that get just the path like path info, but as far as php is concerned, index.php is part of the path.  If you change your rewrite rules to not include the index.php parse_url or pathinfo would work just fine.  It looks like ExpressionEngine is using a regular expression and preg_match.

Comment: codeigniter is using a regex + explode.  There aren't any php functions that do this for you, it is too specific to your application for it to be an inbuilt php function.  Codeigniter is open source, how about looking through the source code? http://docs.gipertext.com/framework/ci170/da/d76/Router_8php-source.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url).

```
parse_url('http://someplace.com/index.php/foo');
/*
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => someplace.com
    [path] => /index.php/foo
)

*/
```

You can then manipulate the `path` item to remove `/index.php`.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, was a function which only returned the '/foo' part. It was supposed to be used with URL's ending with: 'index.php/something/path/random/article/' (so that you could easily use mod_rewrite to take away the index.php part, and the URL's would look nice.)

Comment: This is the most likely, but still doesn't give '/foo/bar' (or /foo , in your example)

Comment: This is what I would have to use if I can't use that function I'm talking about. But I would really like to find that particular function.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a function. It's a variable: `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Comment: @greg: pathinfo does something completely different ;) +1 to compensate

Comment: @greg. did you even read what the pathinfo function does? If you're going to be slapping downvotes on everything, then at least try to make sure you're not wrong and the OP is right in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

That's `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. It may not be available on all systems, it's dependent on th ewebserver passing it on. In Apache, that's the `AcceptPathInfo` option.

response to gregoire:

It's impossible to pull out path_info from a url with 100% reliability unless it's being done on the webserver handling that url at the time - you cannot tell where the actual script part ends and the path_info starts, especially if the path is something like

```
/a/b/c/scriptishere/path/info
```

There's no '.html', or '.php', or '.aspx' or whatever to even given you a hint. As such, this is the only way to 100% reliably answer the OP's question. Anything else is a guess - even "index.php" in the OP's sample could be a directory and the actual script is 'foo'

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always going to have index.php in it, why not just substr, like so:

```
$url = "http://someplace.com/index.php/foo/bar/";
$delim = 'index.php';
$path = substr($url,strpos($url,$delim)+strlen($delim));
```

Thats a little verbose, but if you could clarify where this string is coming from what parts are going to change I could give a more concise answer.

You could also use regular expressions:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('index.php\/(.*)$',$matches);
```

$matches will contain the matched string in index 1, index 0 will be the original string.
I didn't test that regex, but something like that should work.